# NameError in Python script for Cron Implementation

Tags: python, class, schedule

I am trying to perform basic Cron implementation using Python. For which, I created Cron class and tried calling the `my_job()` function. But, I am receiving syntax error. How can I correct the syntax error?

Python Code:

```
import schedule
import time

class Cron:

    def my_job(self):
        print('Foo')

    def Start(self):
        schedule.every(5).to(10).seconds.do(my_job)
        while 1:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)

A = Cron()
A.Start()
```

Following is exception received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cron.py", line 17, in <module>
    A.Start()
  File "cron.py", line 11, in Start
    schedule.every(5).to(10).seconds.do(my_job)
NameError: name 'my_job' is not defined
```

Comment: Use `self.my_job`.

Comment: Got it! Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Read the error. It doesn't say `SyntaxError` but `NameError`.